# Understanding a solution of a differential equation from an approximation (Rauch)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

How does the author obtain formula (4)? From formula (2), I only get that $u\left(\frac{k}{n}+\frac{1}{n},\cdot\right)=\left(1-\frac{c}{n}\partial_x\right)u\left(\frac{k}{n},\cdot\right)$  but I don't see how the exponent $k$ appears as in (4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that for some $k\ge 1$, we have
$$
u(\frac kn, \cdot) \approx (1-\frac{c}{n}\partial_x)^kg(\cdot).\tag{$\ast$}
$$
The case $k = 1$ holds by (2). Again by the approximation (2) and our assumption $(\ast)$,
\begin{align*}
u(\frac kn + \frac 1n,\cdot) &\approx (1-\frac cn\partial_x)u(\frac kn,\cdot)\\
&\approx (1-\frac{c}{n}\partial_x)^{k+1}g(\cdot).
\end{align*}
By induction (4) holds for each $k$.

Answer (score 2):

for one step backward it is what you said:
$$
u(t + \frac{1}{n},.) \approx (1-\frac{c}{n} \partial_x)u(t,.)
$$
so if you start from $t=0$ and use this approximation $k$ times each time with step size $\Delta t = 1/n$ you get:
$$
u(0+\frac{k}{n},.) \approx (1-\frac{c}{n} \partial_x)u(\frac{k-1}{n},.) \\
\approx (1-\frac{c}{n} \partial_x)(1-\frac{c}{n} \partial_x)u(\frac{k-2}{n},.) 
\approx \dots \approx (1-\frac{c}{n} \partial_x)^k u(0,.) = (1-\frac{c}{n} \partial_x)^k g(.)
$$